# User can't print (receives startDocPrinter error)

Tags: windows, printing

A particular user on the network cant print to a particular network printer. The user gets a  "A startDocPrinter Call Was Not Issued" error message.

- user can print to another network printer from same machine.
- the user having the trouble can log onto any other PC on network and print to the network printer without issue
- any other user can log onto the same PC and print to that same network printer with no issues

So, having said that above, the issue seems to be this particular user on this particular machine, printing to that particular network printer ONLY

I did uninstall network printer and reinstall on the particular PC in question

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old
[Microsoft article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180416150507/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889074/nothing-is-printed-when-you-send-a-print-job-to-a-network-printer-serv)
describes these same symptoms :

> This error code means that a StartDocPrinter call was not issued. You receive this error code when the print spooler cannot send data to the port. The print job is marked as "error printing". In this case, the print spooler repeatedly tries to send the data until you cancel the job.

So what this means is that the printer was not available, but you are not getting
the error message why the StartDocPrinter was blocked, but just the message that
it didn't run.

Since this is only happening for one user, I would guess that some product that he
installed is causing the problem.

I suggest examining the user's Startup folder, to see which processes are
starting when he logs-in. Look also for messages in the Event Viewer.

The free
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
might also be useful.